# Symfony service as unique instance

Tags: symfony, service

In the Symfony documentation it says:

"In the service container, all services are shared by default. This means that each time you retrieve the service, you'll get the same instance. This is usually the behavior you want, but in some cases, you might want to always get a new instance."

This is the services.yml

```
services:
    project.notification:
    class: NotificationsBundle\Command\ServerCommand
```

This is the class:

```
class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    public $notification;

    /**
     * Configure a new Command Line
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('Project:notification:server') ->setDescription('Start the notification server.');
    }

    public function getNotification()
    {
        return $this->notification;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->notification = new Notification();
        $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                $this->notification
            )
        ), 8081);

        $server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function ()  {
            $this->notification->sendToAll('Hello');
        });

        $server->run();
    }
}
```

I would like to get the variable `$notification` from another controller. When I do that I got an error "non-existent object" ($notification).

I run the service by executing the following command:

> php app/console Project:notification:server

In the documentation It says I'll get the same instance service but every time I execute:

```
$this->container->get('Project.notification')->notification
```

I got a non-object error. In other words, I lost the object `$notification`  that I created when I ran the service for the first time.
I need to access to the collection list of users (It's inside the object $notification) because I need to send a message from another controller.

Any ideas?

Comment: "This means that each time you retrieve the service, you'll get the same instance." This does not mean that the service is persisted (saved) between calls, it means that only one instance of this service is created per call. So you get a fresh one, but only one, per call.

Comment: So I will change the question to How can I set a persisted service?

Comment: You can do that by saving your data to, for example, a database or session. You cannot have a persisted service unless you keep the php interpreter running 'indefinitely'.

So you could let the getNotification() method check if a notification already exists and if not, create/load one and return that.

Comment: My service is running indefinetely. In any moment I close the window service.

Comment: You just asked the same question and got told that php simply does not work like this.  No matter how you think it should work, running a console command and then expecting the results to be available in a controller is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution:

```
use WebSocket\Client;
        $client = new Client("ws://127.0.0.1:8080"); 
        $client->send("Hello from controller");
```